# Google issues refunding for all subscriptions purchased within 3 days even though I acknowledged the purchase

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I have developed one project which integrated in-app bililng method for Subscription.
It is non-consumable product and it has $3.99 subscribe item per month.
I have used the billing client method 2.1.0 and configured subscription item on Google.
When I tested the app subscription through internal testing, it showed that the item is successfully purchased.
However, the release version has the big risk.
All users subscription are being automatically refunded within 3 days.
The google support team said that the acknowledge all purchases must be done within three days.
Failure to properly acknowledge purchases results in those purchases being refunded.

I integrated acknowledge listener but the result is still same.
I will attach several screenshots which shows how the item is refunded.

[Google issued refund](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDwIx.jpg)

[Payment refunded steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnl1B.png)

Here is the code that I've worked on.
Is there any reason that all items are being automatically refunded because of my code issue?
Thanks for reading and viewing.

```
//build.gradle
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:2.1.0'

//Androidmanifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

//Subscription Purchase and Acknowledge code

class SubscriptionActivity : AppCompatActivity(), PurchasesUpdatedListener {
    lateinit var billingClient: BillingClient
    lateinit var skuList: MutableList<SkuDetails>

    val acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener =
        AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener {
            Toast.makeText(this@SubscriptionActivity, "Purchase acknowledged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subscription)

        setupBillingClient()
        setupInitEvents()

    }

    private fun getAvailableProducts() {
        if (billingClient.isReady)
        {
            val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkusList(Arrays.asList(SubscriptionID))
                .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
                .build()

            billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params)
            {
                    p0, skuDetailsList ->
                if (p0.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK)
                    skuList = skuDetailsList as MutableList<SkuDetails>
                    //displayProduct(skuDetailsList)
                else {
                    //Toast.makeText(this@SubscriptionActivity, "Cannot find product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Toast.makeText(this@SubscriptionActivity, "Billing Client not ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

        private fun setupBillingClient() {
        //billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(this).build()
        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .setListener(this)
            .build();

        billingClient.startConnection(object:BillingClientStateListener{
            override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                //Toast.makeText(this@SubscriptionActivity, "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onBillingSetupFinished(p0: BillingResult) {
                if (p0.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    getAvailableProducts();
                } else {
                    /*
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@SubscriptionActivity,
                        "BillingClient connecting err : " + p0.responseCode,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun setupInitEvents() {
        buttonClose.setOnClickListener {
            closeActivity()
        }

        buttonContainer.setOnClickListener {
            purchase()
        }

        buttonRestorePurchase.setOnClickListener {
            restorePurchase()
        }
    }

    private fun closeActivity() {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, null);
        finish()
    }

    private fun purchase() {
        if (!SpLaunch.getPurchaseToken().isNullOrEmpty())
        {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.restore_title))
                .setMessage("Already Purchased")
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok) { dialog, id ->
                }
                .create().show()
            return
        }

        if (this::skuList.isInitialized && skuList.size > 0) {
            var billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(skuList[0])
                .build()

            val responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams).responseCode

        } else {
            //Toast.makeText(this@SubscriptionActivity, "No Subscription List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
    }

    private fun restorePurchase() {
        //Toast.makeText(this@SubscriptionActivity, "restorePurchase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        if (SpLaunch.getPurchaseToken().isNullOrEmpty())
        {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.restore_title))
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.restore_message))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok) { dialog, id ->

                }
                .create().show()
        } else {
            val url = "https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/" + packageName + "/purchases/subscriptions/" + SubscriptionID + "/tokens/" + SpLaunch.getPurchaseToken() + ":refund"

            HttpTask({
                if (it == null) {
                    //Toast.makeText(this@SubscriptionActivity, "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    return@HttpTask
                }
                //Toast.makeText(this@SubscriptionActivity, "Refund Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                SpLaunch.setPurchaseToken("")
            }).execute("POST", url, "")
        }
    }

    override fun onPurchasesUpdated(p0: BillingResult, p1: MutableList<Purchase>?) {
        if (p0.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && p1 != null) {
            //Toast.makeText(this@SubscriptionActivity, "Purchase Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            for (_pur in p1) {
                var packageName: String = _pur.packageName
                var purchaseToken: String = _pur.purchaseToken
                var purchaseTime: Long = _pur.purchaseTime
                var purchaseState: Int = _pur.purchaseState

                SpLaunch.setPurchasePackage(packageName)
                SpLaunch.setPurchaseToken(purchaseToken)
                SpLaunch.setPurchaseTime(purchaseTime)
                SpLaunch.setPurchaseState(purchaseState)

                handlePurchase(_pur)
            }

            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null)
            finish()
        } else if (p0.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
            //Toast.makeText(this@SubscriptionActivity, "Purchase canceled by User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, null)
            finish()
        } else {
            //Toast.makeText(this@SubscriptionActivity, "Purchase canceled by Error: " + p0.responseCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, null)
            finish()
        }

    }

    private fun handlePurchase(purchase : Purchase)
    {
        //in handlePurchase()
        if (purchase.purchaseState === Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            /*
            val acknowledgePurchaseParams: AcknowledgePurchaseParams =
                AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                    .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
                    .build()

            billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(
                acknowledgePurchaseParams,
                acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener
            )*/

            val params = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
                .build()
            billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(params) { billingResult ->
                val responseCode = billingResult.responseCode
                val debugMessage = billingResult.debugMessage
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        billingClient.endConnection()
    }

}
```

Comment: why do you have two different acknowledge purchase params

Comment: I have blocked that by comments and you can see this param only. 
val params = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
                .build()